# Does casting an IList<T> to an array of type T[] cause enumeration?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, ilist

I have  a method that looks like:

```
T[] field;

public Method(IList<T> argument)
{
    this.field = (T[])argument;
}
```

When the body of the method is executed does enumeration take place during the cast?  Would that change if the underlying type was different?

Comment: On an aside you would want to achieve this in reality by doing field = argument.ToArray() which would enumerate the enumeration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it won't enumerate anything. It will either succeed if `argument` actually *is* a `T[]`, or throw an `InvalidCastException` exception if it isn't. (Or return null if `argument` is null.)

Comment: Shouldn't we say anything about this might be bad design? The caller being able to change the list and why didn't the method take an array in the first place?

Answer (score 4):

If `argument` is a reference to an array (of type `T`), then there is no enumeration — it is a simple cast.

If `argument` is a reference to a `List<T>` or another class that implements IList then there will potentially be a casting exception. (I say potenially as there may be an implict or explict conversion to `T[]` — most likely there won't be).

Edit: as pointed out by Jon, a conversion won't be made in the generic method, so the above parenthesis is incorrect.

Comment: Even if a conversion *does* exist, it won't be used - because the compiler doesn't know about it at compile time.

Comment: @Jon: not sure I follow — I have just tested with an explicit conversion and it cast fine.  Edit: I take it back (mistake in my test).  You are indeed correct.